# Array.splice(index, 0, data) returns mysterious null and increase array size (length)

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I'm trying to place a data into a specific location in an array using array.splice(). So that I can get data from sheet1 to the main sheet in the right column.

Here's how it looks so far. 
 (The Code actually returns correctly at Logger.log)

```
var header1 = data1[0]; //Header of Sheet1
var header2 = data2[0]; //Header of sheet2
var newData = new Array(44); //There are 45 columns

for (i in data1) {
  if (i > 0) { //Take Row by Row Except Header of Sheet1
  var row = data1[i];
  if (row != "") {

    for (j in data2) { //Searching Through All Rows of Sheet2
      var row2 = data2[j];
      if (row[0] == row2[4]) { //If Data In Column Match That Row, Proceed
        //Getting the Right Index of SameName Column
        for (i in header2) {
          var col = header2[i];
          for (j in header1) {
            var col2 = header1[j];
            if (col == col2) {
              Logger.log(j+" "+row2[i]);
              newData.splice(j,0,row2[i]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**It Returns Correctly 1 Line before:**

> Logger.log(j+" "+row2[i]);
>   42 Timestamp 
>   3 Name 
>   4 lastName 
>   2 DoB 
>   0 ID 
> . 
> .
> .
>  1 Type 
>  //All data returns correctly with the correct index (and none is null)

**Here's The Issue:**

> Logger.log(newData); 
>   [ID, Type, null, null, DoB, null, ...., TimeStamp, null, null] 
>   DoB had index at 2 in previous line at Logger.log, but somehow the array has null at pos2.
>   Also... newData.length increases from 44 to 68

Somehow the index and data got mixed up later in the array. 
Thank you in advance to all of you.

Comment: [update] I tried changing the variables to unique vars but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You should not be re-using the index variables in your `for` loops. Rather than `i` and `j` each loop should use a usefully-named variable. As mentioned in the answer, arrays and `for .. in` are bad.

Comment: @tehhowch thank you. I will look for other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you log your newly-instantiated array, you will see that, by default, all array elements are assigned a value of 'null'. In JavaScript, arrays are dynamic, which means their size is not pre-determined.

Assuming that for some rows the condition 'if (row[0] == row2[4])' evaluates to 'false', some indices will be skipped. Naturally, it will produce null elements in your fixed-size array.

Use array literal notation and Array.prototype.push() method to add new elements:

```
var newData = [];
newData.push(element);
```

Also, you shouldn't be using the 'for in' loop for iterating over arrays. Using it is precisely why you don't see 'null' values being logged. More details here [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Ahh! I am not aware of the nature of arrays. Thanks a lot. Will try to come around with new methods. Thanks!